# How do I list all User Accounts with blank EmployeeID attribute from a Specific OU?

Tags: powershell

How i can list all AD User Accounts with a blank employeeid attribute from a specific OU?

```
$OUpath = 'ou=users,ou=random,dc=test,dc=com'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" 

DistinguishedName, Name, UserPrincipalName, | Export-Csv -NoType c:\employeeID
```

At line:9 char:18 + DistinguishedName,Name,UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -NoType c:\employ ... + ~ Missing argument in parameter list. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems. Since `-SearchBase` and `-LDAPFilter` can be used at the same command, combining those would be a good start. The part

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" 
DistinguishedName, Name, UserPrincipalName, | Export-Csv -NoType c:\employeeID
```

Makes little sense. That's because the results of `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)"` aren't used. Maybe a pipe `|` is missing? Then there's a non-terminated list `DistinguishedName, Name, UserPrincipalName, |`. There the problem is the comma after `UserPrincipalName`. Powershell expects more parameters, but there's no such thing.

Try the following version:

```
$OUpath = 'ou=users,ou=random,dc=test,dc=com'
$idlessUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" -SearchBase $OUpath
$idlessUsers | select DistinguishedName, Name, UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -NoType c:\temp\employeeID.csv
```

Comment: How can i add to the query that is not logged in 180 days?

$OUpath = 'ou=users,ou=random,dc=test,dc=com'
$CurrentDate= GET-DATE 
$NumberDays= 180
$idlessUsers | GET-ADUSER -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath  -properties LastLogonDate | where { $_.LastLogonDate.AddDays($NumberDays) -lt $CurrentDate } | Disable-ADAccount 
$idlessUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" -SearchBase $OUpath
$idlessUsers | select  samaccountname, DistinguishedName | Export-Csv -NoType c:\temp\testirun.csv

Comment: @Sheikku One would be looking at `LastLogon` or `LastLogonTimestamp` attributes from AD. Please post a new question if this [article](https://activedirectorypro.com/last-logon-time/) isn't helpful enough.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate your report:

```
$ou = "OU Path"
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties EmployeeID | Where-Object {$_.EmployeeID -like ""} | Select-Object Name,UserPrincipalName,DistinguishedName,EmployeeID | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Temp\EID.csv"
```